# How can i get the subscription id in stripe for canceling the subscription in node.js?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Any ideas Guys? How can i **cancel the subscription** in stripe?

That's my code :

```js
app.post('/cancel-subscription', async(req, res) => {

    const {subscriptionId} = req.body 
    const deleted = await stripe.subscriptions.del(
        stripe.customers.id
      );
    res.send(deleted);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Stripe's API, but their documentation for cancelling a subscription (https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel?lang=node) gives an example like:

```
const deleted = await stripe.subscriptions.del(
  'sub_AgOem0qdyCowxn'
);
```

So, in your case, try something like:

```
app.post('/cancel-subscription', async(req, res) => {
    const { subscriptionId } = req.body;
    const deleted = await stripe.subscriptions.del(subscriptionId);
    res.send("Cancelled the subscription"); // Just an example, include whatever response necessary.
});
```

However:

1. This assumes that the subscription ID is present within the request's body (under `subscriptionId` property).
2. Double check if it's safe/recommended to send the contents of `deleted` in its entirety back to the client (in case it contains anything sensitive). You might also need to use `res.json` instead of `res.send` (depending on the data type).